# How to parse time with separated nano-second

Tags: java, time-format

I get some file with time format `13:25:30.345:567:345`. Where "`345:567:345`" is the nanosecond part. One way to parse it is remove all ":" and parse with time formatter `HHmmss.SSSSSSSSS`. However, I just wonder, can I just use time formatter to parse it without pre-processing?

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: I could not come up with any good way to do it... I guess just stick with what you've got.

Comment: HI azro, it is not a really difficult problem to solve, as mentioned I can remove all ":" and parse it. I just wonder if there is any way to do that in the formatter which I don't know. And I did review the API document, I just wonder if I missed something

Comment: For what it’s worth, I played a bit around with `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendValue` and attempts at home-grown `TemporalField`s for micro of milli and nano of micro, but couldn’t get it to work immediately. There probably is a way through, but it’s not trivial.

Comment: I see thanks for suggestion